# Form error on mobile but not desktop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have found a bug with my html form that I can't debug. I have changed the formatting of the form twice, but nothing has helped on that aspect. If you would like to see how the form itself it is located at http://driveforeagle.com/apply/page2/

Please note that you will need to visit the link in order to understand what I am referencing along with references to my code below.

**The Bug**

On mobile devices only (no disparagement between device types), when you go down to the "Driving Experience" section, the two subsections "Traffic Citation History" and "Driver's License History"; the input fields within these two subsection are not clickable and are unable to be filled out. Almost like there is some kind of floating section, but I have not been able to locate where this floating section would be coming from.

**Driving Experience Section**

```
<article class='panel panel-danger'>
    <header class='panel-heading' role='tab' id='drivingExperienceHeading'>
        <h4 class='panel-title'>
            <a class='collapsed' role='button' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#panelMenu' href='#drivingExperience' aria-expanded='false' aria-controls='drivingExperience'> 
            Driving Experience
            </a>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right'></span>
        </h4>
    </header>
    <div id='drivingExperience' class='panel-collapse collapse' role='tabpanel' aria-labelledby='drivingExperienceHeading'>
        <main class='panel-body'>
            <? require_once 'sections/driving_experience.php'; ?>
        </main>
    </div>
</article>
```

**require_once 'sections/driving_experience.php'**

```
<article class='col-xs-12'>
<h5><strong>List all driving experience for the past 10 years</strong></h5>
</article>
<article class='col-xs-12'>
    <h4>Tractor Trailer Experience</h4>
</article>
<section class='clearfix'></section>
<article class='form-group col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
    <label class='control-label req'>From</label>
    <input type='text' class='form-control addr-date' id='tt-from-date' name='tt-from-date' data-validator='notEmpty|isDateMMYYYY'/>
</article>
<article class='form-group col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
    <label class='control-label req'>To</label>
    <input type='text' class='form-control addr-date' id='tt-to-date' name='tt-to-date' data-validator='notEmpty|isDateMMYYYY'/>
</article>
<article class='form-group col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
    <label class='control-label req'>Approximate Miles</label>
    <input type='text' class='form-control' name='tt-miles' id='tt-miles' data-validator='notEmpty|isNumber'/>
</article>
<article class='col-xs-12'>
    <hr />
    <h4>Straight Truck Experience</h4>
</article>
<article class='form-group col-xs-12'>
    <section class='checkbox'>
        <label> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="st_exp"/> No Straight-Truck Experience
        </label>
    </section>
</article>
<article class='form-group col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
    <label class='control-label req'>From</label>
    <input type='text' class='form-control addr-date' id='st-from-date' name='st-from-date' data-validator='notEmpty|isDateMMYYYY'/>
</article>
<article class='form-group col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
    <label class='control-label req'>To</label>
    <input type='text' class='form-control addr-date' id='st-to-date' name='st-to-date' data-validator='notEmpty|isDateMMYYYY'/>
</article>
<article class='form-group col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
    <label class='control-label req'>Approximate Miles</label>
    <input type='text' class='form-control not-empty' id='st-miles' name='st-miles' data-validator='notEmpty|isNumber'/>
</article>
<article class='col-xs-12'>
    <hr />
    <h4>Accident History</h4>
</article>
<article class='col-xs-12'>
    <h5><strong>List all accident records for the past 5 years regardless of fault.</strong></h5>
</article>
<article class='form-group col-xs-12'>
    <section class='checkbox'>
        <label> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="no_accidents" />No Accident History
        </label>
    </section>
</article>
<section id='accident-holder'>
    <article class='accident-form last'>
        <section class='form-group col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
            <label class='control-label req'>Date</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-control addr-date accident-date' name='accident-date' data-validator='notEmpty|isDateUS'/>
        </section>
        <section class='form-group col-md-3 col-sm6 col-xs-12'>
            <label class='control-label req'>Nature</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-control nature' name="nature" data-validator='notEmpty'/>
        </section>
        <section class='form-group col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
            <label class='control-label req'>Location</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-control location' name='location' data-validator='notEmpty'/>
        </section>
        <section class='form-group col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6'>
            <label class='control-label req'>No. of Fatalities</label>
            <input type='tel' class='form-control fatalities' name='fatalities' data-validator='notEmpty|isNumber'>
        </section>
        <section class='form-group col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6'>
            <label class='control-label req'>No. of Injuries</label>
            <input type='tel' class='form-control injuries' name='injuries' data-validator='notEmpty|isNumber'>
        </section>
    </article>
</section>
<section class='clearfix'></section>
<article class='form-group col-md-12'>
    <a href="" id="add_accident">Add Another Accident Record</a>
</article>
<!-- BEGIN TRAFFIC CITATION HISTORY -->
<article class='col-xs-12'>
    <hr />
    <h4>Traffic Citation History</h4>
</article>
<article class='col-xs-12'>
    <h5>
        <strong>List all traffic citations, convictions, supervision and forfeitures for the last 5 years (other than parking).</strong>
    </h5>
</article>
<article class='form-group col-xs-12'>
    <section class='checkbox'>
        <label> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="no_citations" />No Citations
        </label>
    </section>
</article>
<section id='traffic-holder'>
    <article class='traffic-citation-form last'>
        <section class='form-group col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
            <label class='control-label req'>Location</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-control citation-location' name='citation-location' data-validator='notEmpty'/>
        </section>
        <section class='form-group col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
            <label class='control-label req'>Date</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-control addr-date citation-date' name='citation-date' data-validator='notEmpty'/>
        </section>
        <section class='form-group col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
            <label class='control-label req'>Charge</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-control charge' name='charge' data-validator='notEmpty'/>
        </section>
        <section class='form-group col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
            <label class='control-label req'>Penalty</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-control penalty' name='penalty' data-validator='notEmpty'/>
        </section>
    </article>
</section>
<article class='col-md-12'>
    <a href="" id="add_citation">Add Another Traffic Citation Record</a>
</article>
    <!-- BEGIN DRIVER LICENSE HISTORY -->
<article class='col-xs-12'>
    <hr />
    <h4>Driver's License History</h4>
</article>
<article class='col-xs-12'>
    <h5>
        <strong>List every driver's license held in the past 3 years</strong>
    </h5>
</article>
<section id='license-holder'>
    <article class='license-form last'>
        <section class='form-group col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'>
            <label class='control-label req'>State</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-control license_state' name='license_state' data-validator='notEmpty'/>
        </section>
        <section class='form-group col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
            <label class='control-label req'>License No.</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-control license_no' name='license_no' data-validator='notEmpty'/>
        </section>
        <section class='form-group col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'>
            <label class='control-label req'>Type</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-control license_type' name='license_type' data-validator='notEmpty'/>
        </section>
        <section class='form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
            <label class='control-label req'>Endorsements</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-control endorsements' name='endorsements' data-validator='notEmpty'/>
        </section>
        <section class='form-group col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
            <label class='control-label req'>Exp. Date</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-control addr-date license_date' name='license_date' data-validator='notEmpty|isDateMMYYYY'/>
        </section>
    </article>
</section>
<section class='col-md-12'>
    <a href='' id='add_license'>Add Another Driver's License</a>
</section>
<section class='form-group col-xs-12'>
    <hr />
    <label class='control-label radio req'>
        A. Have you ever been denied a license, permit or privilege to operate a motor vehicle?
    </label>
    <label class='radio-inline'>
        <input type='radio' class="radio-check" name='qa' value='1' data-validator='groupNotEmpty'> Yes
    </label>
    <label class='radio-inline'>
        <input type='radio' class="radio-check" name='qa' value='-1'> No
    </label>
</section>
<section class='form-group col-xs-12'>
    <label class='control-label'>If "Yes" please explain:</label>
    <textarea rows='5' id='qa-explain'  name='qa_explain' class='form-control' readonly></textarea>
</section>
<section class='form-group col-xs-12'>  
    <label class='control-label radio req'>
        B. Has any license, permit or privilege ever been suspended or revoked?
    </label>
    <label class='radio-inline'>
        <input type='radio' class="radio-check" name='qb' value='1' data-validator='groupNotEmpty'> Yes
    </label>
    <label class='radio-inline'>
        <input type='radio' class="radio-check" name='qb' value='-1'> No
    </label>
</section>
<section class='form-group col-xs-12'>
    <label class='control-label'>If "Yes" please explain:</label>
    <textarea rows='5' id='qb-explain' name='qb_explain' class='form-control' readonly></textarea>
</section>
<section class='form-group col-xs-12'>
    <label class='control-label radio req'>
        C. Have you ever tested positive or refused a test, on any pre-employment drug or alchohol test administered by an employer to which you applied, but did not obtain safety-sensitive transportation work covered by DOT agency drug and alcohol testing rules during the past two years?
    </label>
    <label class='radio-inline'>
        <input type='radio' class="radio-check" name='qc' value='1' data-validator='groupNotEmpty'> Yes
    </label>
    <label class='radio-inline'>
        <input type='radio' class="radio-check" name='qc' value='-1'> No
    </label>
</section>
<section class='form-group col-xs-12'>
    <label class='control-label radio'>
        If "Yes", can you provide documentation that you successfully passed then returned to work?
    </label>
    <label class='radio-inline'>
        <input type='radio' class='' name='qc_explain' value='1' disabled> Yes
    </label>
    <label class='radio-inline'>
        <input type='radio' class='' name='qc_explain' value='-1' disabled> No
    </label>
</section>
<section class='col-xs-12 form-group'>
    <label class='control-label radio'>
        D. Have you ever been denied access to the mail, or had your postal badge revoked?<span class='req'> *</span>
    </label>
    <label class='radio-inline'>
        <input type='radio' class="radio-check" name='qd' value='1' data-validator='groupNotEmpty'> Yes
    </label>
    <label class='radio-inline'>
        <input type='radio' class="radio-check" name='qd' value='-1'> No
    </label>
</section>
<section class='clearfix'></section>
```

My apologies for the length of the second file but I added the entirety of the section in order to make sure all the code was there for analysis. Again I find nothing abnormal about the form itself, I can't find any missing tags, unclosed tags, or anything like that, so again this just isn't making much sense.

On another note I also do use some javascript to manipulate the forms as well because the user can add another piece of information, so it clones the form. I'm not sure if that has some effect on it either, however no cloned forms exist at the start so I'm assuming it doesn't. I will include it for completion anyway.

**Javascript Sample**

```
 //generate an object of data to consolidate the amount of further coding needed

var multisections = {
'address' : [
    "#add_address",
    "#address-holder",
    ".address-form"
],
'employment' : [
    "#add_employment",
    "#employment-holder",
    ".employment-form"
],
'accident' : [
    "#add_accident",
    "#accident-holder",
    ".accident-form"
],
'citation' : [
    "#add_citation",
    "#traffic-holder",
    ".traffic-citation-form"
],
'license' : [
    "#add_license",
    "#license-holder",
    ".license-form"
]
};


$.each(multisections, function(i, e){
   $(e[0]).on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var parentEl = $(e[1]);
    var lastForm = $.makeArray($(parentEl).find('.last'));  

    var currF = $(lastForm).find('input[name*="fmscr_"]:checked').val();
    var currD = $(lastForm).find('input[name*="drug_testing_"]:checked').val();
    var lastFmscr = $(lastForm).find('input[name*="fmscr_"]').attr('name');
    var lastDrug = $(lastForm).find('input[name*="drug_testing_"]').attr('name');
    var newForm = $(lastForm).clone(true);
    $(newForm).addClass('last replica');
    $(newForm).find('.delete-record').remove();
    $(newForm).prepend('<div class="col-xs-12"><button class="delete-record btn btn-warning pull-right" value="delete">&times</button></div>');
    $(newForm).insertAfter(lastForm);
    $(lastForm).removeClass('last');   
    var i;
   if(e[1] == "#employment_history"){ 

        i = lastFmscr.substr(lastFmscr.length -1); //get the current count
        i = parseInt(i); //turn it to an int
        i++; //increase the count          
        $(newForm).find('input[name="fmscr_'+(i-1)+'"]').attr('name', 'fmscr_'+i);
        $(newForm).find('input[name="drug_testing_'+(i-1)+'"]').attr('name', 'drug_testing_'+i);

    }
    $(newForm).find('input:not([type=radio]), select').val("");
    $(lastForm).find('input[name*="fmscr_"][value='+currF+']').prop('checked', true);
    $(lastForm).find('input[name*="drug_testing_"][value='+currD+']').prop('checked', true);   
    $(newForm).find('input[name="fmscr_'+i+'"]').prop('checked', false);
    $(newForm).find('input[name="drug_testing_'+i+'"]').prop('checked', false);
    newForm.find('.addr-date').each(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('id').removeClass('hasDatepicker');
        $('.addr-date').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'mm/yy',
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                validator('#applicationForm');
                checkHeadings();
            }
        });

    });
    validator('#applicationForm');
    checkHeadings();
});
$(e[2]).on('click', '.delete-record', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest(e[2]).prev().addClass('last')
    $(this).closest('.replica').remove();
    validator('#applicationForm');
    checkHeadings();
});
});
```

If there is anything else that anyone would like to see further regarding the code please let me know and I will get it to you as soon as possible! Thank you ahead of time for all and any assistance.

Comment: have you tried in commenting the javascript part step by step? Maybe it blows up with the mobile.

Comment: Yes I've tried that. Also what do you mean by "it" blows up on mobile?

Comment: Could be that you are using any special tag of those? have a look: http://quirksmode.org/html5/inputs/mobile.html I'm not such and expert in frontend

Comment: is more like design problem check your `<section>` and `<article>` tags, they may b closed properly but overlapping in mobile devices more like css /HTML5 render issue, i see some places css is like `<section><article>somestuff</article></section>` and other no `<section>` just `<article>` tag, try to use `class="clearfix"` it may b the short and quick solution, when i try to inspect element of  input, the console highlight another `<section>` my suggestion put all `<article>` tag inside `<section>`

Comment: Using my mobile device (Nexus 5) + chrome mobile inspector I can see that those fields aren't able to gain focus or check checkboxes even when programmitcally sending a command like `$('.checkbox').prop('checked',true)` in the JS console. This leads me to believe it's not a floating div in the way or CSS error. There is probably a broken or unclosed HTML tag somewhere in your mobile template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed a `<section class="clearfix"></section>` just before

`<article class="col-md-12">
    <a href="" id="add_citation">Add Another Traffic Citation Record</a>
</article>`

part, as before the

`<section class="col-md-12">
        <a href="" id="add_license">Add Another Driver's License</a>
</section>`

With a Firebug or similar, right click on the unclickable input field and "inspect element", it will bring you to the faulty element, the link which is covering the whole part of the form.

The cause needed a bit more reseach... As I understand it, the thing is that all your `col-*-*` stuff is `float: left;` so they do not make their container bigger, the height stays 0. The `<article>` element containing the link to add traffic citation or driving licence is also `float: left;` on bigger screens but is NOT floated on smaller screens.

Not 100% sure of this, but since it is not a float, it needs to be at least as big as the elements before to be placed after them, and it covers the preceding section (an element coming later in the code will cover the preceding elements). Floats usually needs to be cleared, in order to avoid weird things...

Comment: You are correct, that is the solution, but why is that the fix? I remember it was explained to me once but I'm not exactly sure why?

Comment: @MarkHill Good it solved the problem. Me too, not exactly sure why, but updated the answer to partly add about why.

Comment: you can use clearfix or `<br style="clear:both;">` to clear both side of the floating and revert the page to be rendered "normally". If you use float to position some elements (eg. columns) then you have to clear this property to revert to the normal positioning